# How to import python module from other directory, but it is using function from other modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

I'm trying to import a class in another folder, but that class has functions using functions from a submodule. When I run main.py in module1, I had this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/python/module1/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    import module2.module2class
  File "D:\python\module2\module2class.py", line 1, in <module>
    from submodule.submodule2.submodule2func import submodule2func1, submodule2func2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'submodule'
```

My directory is like this:

```
folder  
|---- module1
|    |---- __init__.py
|    |---- main.py
|
|---- module2
      |---- submodule
      |     |---- __init__.py
      |     |---- submodule1
      |     |---- submodule2
      |           |---- __init__.py
      |           |---- submodule2func.py
      |
      |---- __init__.py
      |---- module2class.py
      |---- main.py
```

=====================================
module1 folder:
main.py:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import os

a = os.path.join(Path(__file__).parent.parent.resolve(),"")
sys.path.insert(1, a)
import module2.module2class

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = module2.module2class.Speak("OK")
    a.say()
    a.moduleused()
```

================================
module2 folder is comprised of:
main.py:

```
import module2class

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("This is module 2 main")
    md2c = module2class.Speak("I'm module2's class")
    md2c.say()
    md2c.moduleused()
```

module2class.py:

```
from submodule.submodule2.submodule2func import submodule2func1, submodule2func2


class Speak:
    def __init__(self, line):
        self.line = line

    def say(self):
        print(self.line)

    def moduleused(self):
        submodule2func1()
        submodule2func2()
```

submodule2func.py:

```
def submodule2func1():
    print("I'm submodule2's function 1")


def submodule2func2():
    print("I'm submodule2's function 2")
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is because it cannot locate submodule, thus import sequence is partial. Python by default only check the working directory for modules, thus in order to switch to other directory, you need to add path. In this case, there MUST be a **init**.py in the specified directory for Python to consider it a module. You have this though.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/module2/submodule/submodule2/')
from submodule2.submodule2func import submodule2func1, submodule2func2
```

Comment: I was able to fix the error by fixing module2class.py  
from  
```
from submodule.submodule2.submodule2func import submodule2func1, submodule2func2
```
to 
```
from module2.submodule.submodule2.submodule2func import submodule2func1, submodule2func2
```
but now when I run module2class.py alone, it give me this error:  
```
Traceback:
  File "d:/python/module2/module2class.py", line 1, in <module>
    from module2.submodule.submodule2.submodule2func import submodule2func1, submodule2func2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module2'
```
but runing main.py in module1 is ok